# Given an uint8_t, find out how many bits are set

Tags: c++, binary

I do have an 8-bit unsigned integer and I'd like to know how many of its bits are set to 1.
There is a trivial way by AND-ing (&) it with 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x0F, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80, 0xF0 and incrementing a variable for each one of those which is not zero, but I'd like to hear more sophisticated solutions.

Comment: You can use a loop and the bit shift operator.

Comment: Besides @Barry's answer, here some fun methods: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [builtin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html):

```
int bits_set(uint8_t x) {
    return __builtin_popcount(x);
}
```

Or make a table:

```
int bits_set(uint8_t x) {
    // easy enough to generate this
    static const uint8_t table[] = {0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, ... };

    // then it's just a lookup
    return table[x];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a while loop with bitshifting:

```
uint8_t someInt = 13;
int num_ones = 0;

while (someInt)
{
    num_ones += someInt & 1;
    someInt = someInt >> 1;
}
```